# Declare variables returned with symvar (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, variables, symbolic-math, declare, symbolic-computation

I'm trying to declare a function (n-dimensional) and its variables from an input, regardless of how many variables I have in this function. Example:

```
input_func = '3*x*y^2 + x^3 -3*x'
```

I use `symvar` to get these variables and it works just fine:

```
>> test = symvar('3*x*y^2 + x^3 -3*x')

test = 

    'x'
    'y'
```

Unfortunately, I can't use this output to declare these variables directly. Could you help me with that?

Btw, I'm using MATLAB R2013a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
>> vars = symvar('3*x*y^2 + x^3 -3*x');
>> syms(vars{:})
>> whos x y
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  x         1x1               112  sym                
  y         1x1               112  sym
```